# PHP CORE Warning Randomly Occurs On New PHP Windows Install

Tags: php, windows, php-ini

```
ERROR TYPE: E_CORE_WARNING 
MESSAGE: Cannot open 'C:\Program Files ' for reading 
SITE PAGE: https://domain.com/online-store/categories.php
IP ADDRESS: 108.88.128.225 
ERROR TIME: September 9, 2014 7:35 am 
USER AGENT: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0;     GTB7.5; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
```

I'm getting the above error on all PHP sites on a new windows server we built. 
Basically the error occurs randomly usually about every 30 minutes to 1 hour randomly on page and can never be recreated. Usually if the error comes up you simply click refresh and the page is okay again.

It says E_CORE_WARNING, so I'm assuming its got to be something in the PHP INI File or the Installation.

Comment: The better question is, why is it trying to open C:\Program Files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we didn't have the session path set in the PHP INI File.

Basically we set it to this and that fixed the issue.

```
session.save_path = C:\php\sessions
```